# Make scrollTop to always check

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing a scrollTop jQuery function, and it is working very nice, see it below:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var top = $(document).scrollTop();
        if (top >= 1225) {
            // Do something
        }
    });
});
```

However, if the user have his `scrollTop`, in that case, higher than 1225, and the script isn't fully loaded, the function will not happen, just if he scroll the page again. Isn't there a way to make the `scrollTop` to always check, not just if the user Scrolls the page?

Thanks a lot in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, trigger the event yourself.

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var top = $(document).scrollTop();
        if (top >= 1225) {
            // Do something
        }
    }).triggerHandler("scroll");
});
```

Comment: Awesome, really impressive,Thanks a lot for answer me.

Comment: nice little function :D